# 'Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps' Tutorial unable to load markers

Tags: php, mysql, xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have followed almost every line in what is given in this tutorial - https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

The code for phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php is:

```
<?
$host = "localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="Resfeber_Labs";
?>
```

The code for phpsqlajax_genxml3.php is:

```
<?php

require("phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php");

// Start XML file, create parent node

$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect ($host, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table

$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header('Content-type: text/xml');

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each

while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

The code for ajax_map_v3.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[

  var customIcons = {
    restaurant: {
      icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
    },
    bar: {
      icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
    }
  };

  function load() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
    downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml3.php", function(data) {
      var xml = data.responseXML;
      var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
        var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
        var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: point,
          icon: icon.icon
        });
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
      }
    });
  }

  function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infoWindow.setContent(html);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  }

  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, false);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}

  //]]>

</script>

</head>

<body onload="load()">
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have been through numerous posts regarding the same, and still haven't been able to load the markers onto the displayed map.
The XML returns just fine and looks like this:

```
<markers>
    <marker name="Pan Africa Market" address="1521 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.608940" lng="-122.340141" type="restaurant"/>
    <marker name="Buddha Thai & Bar" address="2222 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613590" lng="-122.344391" type="bar"/>
    <marker name="The Melting Pot" address="14 Mercer St, Seattle, WA" lat="47.624561" lng="-122.356445" type="restaurant"/>
    <marker name="Ipanema Grill" address="1225 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.606365" lng="-122.337654" type="restaurant"/>
    <marker name="Sake House" address="2230 1st Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.612823" lng="-122.345673" type="bar"/>
    <marker name="Crab Pot" address="1301 Alaskan Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.605961" lng="-122.340363" type="restaurant"/>
    <marker name="Mama's Mexican Kitchen" address="2234 2nd Ave, Seattle, WA" lat="47.613976" lng="-122.345467" type="bar"/>
    <marker name="Wingdome" address="1416 E Olive Way, Seattle, WA" lat="47.617214" lng="-122.326584" type="bar"/>
    <marker name="Piroshky Piroshky" address="1908 Pike pl, Seattle, WA" lat="47.610126" lng="-122.342834" type="restaurant"/>
</markers>
```

Any help regarding loading the markers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Let's assume the tutorial is correct and works(I'm sure), how should we give an answer by the given information(e.g. returned errors would be interesting), the posted code is a 100%-copy of the tutorial.

Comment: On chrome in the console log, the errors are: 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/Resfeber_Labs/maps/phpsqlajax_genxml3.xml. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. ajax_map_v3.html:71
downloadUrl ajax_map_v3.html:71
load ajax_map_v3.html:29
onload ajax_map_v3.html:82


Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///opt/lampp/htdocs/Resfeber_Labs/maps/phpsqlajax_genxml3.xml'. ajax_map_v3.html:71
downloadUrl ajax_map_v3.html:71
load ajax_map_v3.html:29
onload ajax_map_v3.html:82

Comment: Run the ajax_map_v3.html on a webserver, not on filesystem

Comment: @Dr.Molle Running it on the webserver, the error is http://i.imgur.com/udHIive.png

Comment: It works now! I had set the request.open statement to false, which had to be made true and the file had to be run on web server.

Comment: Pleased this is solved. Would you add an answer to explain what the issue was, and accept it by clicking the tick? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is rather simple and contrary to the popular notion that I've gathered across multiple questions, the google maps api are correct. The file has to be hosted on the web server instead of the filesystem. Also, the request.open statement should not be set to false, and should be left to be set true.